# Gatling Performance and load testing with Camunda BPMN

Tags: scala, load-testing, bpmn, gatling, camunda

I am working on an application using Camunda BPMN. This application calls restful 
services for fetching or saving or updating data in the backend. I want to write load performance tests for this application. I am able to test indivisual endpoints with scala scripts in gatling. But how to test one entire BPMN workflow ? Is there any headstart material that I can refer?

Answer (score 1):

Load and performance testing is a very complicated topic and usually depends on number of external environment factors.

I think a good starting point would be a [user guide](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.7/user-guide/testing/) and our [examples repository](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-examples) to get general idea on testing practices.

Once you have chosen your way of testing the whole process you then would have to identify parameters that simulate high load in your environment and adjust them in your test.